# Can be Replacement a Way to Deal with Nonresponse?

Tags: sampling, inference, bias, survey-sampling, non-response

When I've asked a teacher (in the past) about how could I handle, in a survey with simple random sampling, the participants I couldn't reach for some reason, he told me that I could use a pre established "replacement procedure" (and by replacement, he doesn't mean the usual concept of selecting the same individual more than once).

According to him, I could (prior to the survey) state that, for instance, non-respondents (after applying some criteria), could be disregarded and replaced by some new randomly assigned population member. So, if I prior design some strict procedure for that, the sampling wouldn't be biased by nonresponse - or would be less biased, at least.

So here's my question: **Is there any literature and/or reasonable foundations supporting this method? What are the main advantages and drawbacks of this approach? And what are the other alternatives?**

Considering that I have rich prior information about the population members, does it change anything in the approach choice for mitigating nonresponse?

> Edit Summary
>
> > 1. Reframed question after comment and further reading.
> > 2. "New randomly assigned respondent" was misexpressing what I've meant, giving the idea of replacement using another respondent's response! "New randomly assigned population member" better expresses my question, that is selecting a new random participant.

Comment: You're talking about using existing responses to impute the missing responses. There's absolutely no way to answer your question with YES or NO. It's one of the possibilities.

Comment: @SmallChess, so, should I edit and ask about the advantages and drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: Done. Please, confirm if it's better now, @SmallChess. Thanks for your feedback!!

Comment: I'm just wondering... If I do that, wouldn't I be creating another bias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the nonresponding units is indeed a common practice in survey statistics. (Mind you, the practice of survey statistics is about as remote from sampling books and classes as the practice of software development is from `printf("Hello world!\n")` programs.) Even though they seem like data cleaning procedures, the substitution procedures have to be a part of the design, as survey inference is with respect to randomness in who's in the sample, not with respect to the observed values (which is what frequentist statistics $x_i \sim \mbox{i.i.d.} f(x,\theta)$ teaches you).

Some references include:

- Rubin and Zanutto, "Using Matched Substitutes" Chapter 26 in [Groves et al (2002), *Survey Nonresponse*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471396273)
- [Nishimura's 2015 Ph.D. dissertation at Michigan](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/113439/raphaeln_1.pdf?sequence=1), with additional references therein.

The topic is more of an art than science; several other books I was honestly expecting to at least mention it ([Longford's *Missing Data and SAE*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852337605); [Kim and Shao's *Methods for Handling Incomplete Data*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439849633); [*Handbook of Missing Data Methodology*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439854610)) have zero coverage.

My gut feeling is that substitution works best by combining design procedures with some sort of modeling of nonresponse propensities, but probably Nishimura's dissertation gives a better reasoned set of recommendations than my guts do.